# html javascript ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I m validating variables from html inputs in ajax javascript .

What i m trying to do for sure is when client Click the Submit button which it variable is **var sub** another div from html file should appear but after completing to fill the required fields.

But when i tried doing it i get no response means the html div that should appear

**HTML**

```
            <span id="formst">User name:<input type="text" name="username" id="user" onBlur="checkU();"/>
            <div id="staut"></div>
            <br /><br />
            Phone Number:<input type="tel" name="number" id="tel" value="+255" />
            <div id="stau"></div>
            <br /><br />
            <h3>Your Description</h3>
            <textarea rows="6" cols="22" id="textarea" ></textarea><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" onClick ="payment();" id="sub"/>
            <div id="st"></div>
            </span>
        </form>


<div id="payment2">

            <ul id="adjustPay">
                <li id="tigo" onClick="Tigo();">Tigo Pesa</li>
                <li id="voda">Vodacom Mpesa</li>
                <li id="air">AirTel Money</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and ajax javascript  Jquery code

```
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "function.php");
    info.innerHTML = "Please wait ...";
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true){

    if(ajax.responseText != "please wait"){
        info.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        sb.style.display = "block";

        }else if(ajax.responseText = "please wait"){

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#form").show(function(){
            $("#form").slideUp(3840);
            $("#payment2").show();

        });
    });
}


        }
    }

    ajax.send("u="+u+"&n="+n+"&t="+t);

}
```

Problem is on **else if(ajax.responseTex = "please wait")**

please if there is any way of doing this just show me

Comment: Where is function payment and where is the code to stop submission? Also = is assigment and == or === is test for equality, also you cannot have a document.ready inside an ajax callback. There is little working code here

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using jQuery's ajax function?

Comment: function payment() it was before variable ajax = ajaxObj() . I tried place it their but it result to be problem so i delete it. and about Jquery document.ready if for sliding up my html div . I i couldn't find other way of doing it @mplungjan

Comment: because i only know this way @Andy

Comment: Then i suggest you have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this - you need to change #sb and data to reflect the actual element and the data returned

```js
$(function(){
  $("#form").on("submit",function(e) { // when submitted
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel the submission
    $("#info").html("Please wait ...");
    $.post(function.php",$("#form").serialize(),function(data) {
     if (data != "please wait"){
       $("#info").html(data);
       $("#sb).show();
     else {
      $("#form").show(function(){
        $("#form").slideUp(3840);
        $("#payment2").show();
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan. but i need if the response from php file is equal to PLEASE WAIT $("#payment2").show(); then to slideUp();

Comment: And what is the problem ? You have to amend my suggestion to fit the exact situation

Comment: The problem i see from your code is if (data != "please wait"){
       $("#info").html(data);
       $("#sb).show();

Comment: Yes if it is NOT "please wait", show the data otherwise show the form

Comment: That i guess should be $("#sb") which is submit button should display  block which means $("#payment2") which is sliding should not slide   @mplungjan

Comment: Show() is jquery for display block.

Comment: Now i got u Thank you  @mplungjan